# How to use STC instruction in the ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

Can someone give example of STC in ARM
As per the cortex A

```
STC(Store Coprocessor Registers) writes a coprocessor register to memory (or multiple
```

registers, if Lis specified).
Syntax
       STC{L}{cond} coproc, CRd, [Rn]

But some example can help

is it some thing like
     STC CP15, CP15,r1

Answer (score 1):

The [standard assembly names](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1359731137632.html) for coprocessors are *p0*-*p15*, and *c0*-*c15* for coprocessor registers, so the *coproc* and *CRd* fields for [STC](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361289906120.html) would look like this:

```
STC p10, c2, [r0]
```

However, it may be worth noting that you're unlikely to get much use out of the STC instruction without some custom coprocessor to use it on, since the behaviour and meaning of the generic coprocessor instructions is defined by the coprocessor itself. Of the standard coprocessor interfaces defined in the architecture, CP14 and CP15 mostly don't support generic operations other than MCR/MRC (so STC would give you an undefined exception on anything except the one debug register that allows it), and CP10/CP11 (VFP and NEON) have their own more usable mnemonics - the above example is actually the 'raw' form of `vstr s4, [r0]`.